# Power BI - DAX Multiple lookups?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have some raw data

[image: Raw Data]

Now I want to write some DAX so I can go to this:

[image: Finished Table]

As you can see, I was able to get one date in there.  This is the DAX I used:

```
Last MT 1 Date = 
CALCULATE (
    VALUES ( Main_Tanks_Last[Last Date].[Date] ),
    FILTER ( Main_Tanks_LAST, [Main Tank 1 ID] = VALUES( Main_Tanks[Tank ID] ) )
)
```

So, how can I get a single column so that it looks at the tank to determine it's ID and compare it to Main Tank 1 ID, Main Tank 2 ID or Main Tank 3 ID and fill in the date?  And, so that it doesn't throw an error if there isn't a tank 1 2 or 3.

Data was imported from SQL server 2014.

**ADDED INFO**

So the raw data comes from this SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @MT1_ID AS INT, @MT2_ID AS INT, @MT3_ID AS INT

SELECT DISTINCT
    IBX_Name AS "IBX",
    (SELECT ([Tank_ID]) FROM Tanks WHERE Tanks.fk_IBX_ID = IBXs.IBX_ID AND Tanks.Main_Tank_Index = 1) AS "Main Tank 1 ID",
    AST_UST_Level1 AS "Latest Main Tank 1 Level",
    (SELECT ([Tank_ID]) FROM Tanks WHERE Tanks.fk_IBX_ID = IBXs.IBX_ID AND Tanks.Main_Tank_Index = 2) AS "Main Tank 2 ID",
    AST_UST_Level2 AS "Latest Main Tank 2 Level",
    (SELECT ([Tank_ID]) FROM Tanks WHERE Tanks.fk_IBX_ID = IBXs.IBX_ID AND Tanks.Main_Tank_Index = 3) AS "Main Tank 3 ID",
    AST_UST_Level3 AS "Latest Main Tank 3 Level",
    RunData_Date AS "Last Date"
FROM RunData 

INNER JOIN Tanks ON Tanks.fk_GeneratorName_ID = RunData.fk_GeneratorName_ID
INNER JOIN IBXs ON IBXs.IBX_ID = Tanks.fk_IBX_ID
INNER JOIN GeneratorNames ON GeneratorNames.GeneratorName_ID = RunData.fk_GeneratorName_ID

WHERE ([RunData_Date] = (SELECT Max([RunData_Date]) FROM RunData AS T1 WHERE T1.fk_IBX_ID = IBX_ID AND (T1.AST_UST_Level1 > 0 OR T1.AST_UST_Level2 > 0 OR T1.AST_UST_Level3 > 0)))
```

This is actually a small set of a larger data set:

```
IBX        Generator                                          Main Tank 1 ID Latest Main Tank 1 Level Main Tank 2 ID Latest Main Tank 2 Level Main Tank 3 ID Latest Main Tank 3 Level Last Date
---------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------- ------------------------ -------------- ------------------------ -------------- ------------------------ ----------
DC2        DC2-Generator-1                                    1              16128                    2              16192                    NULL           NULL                     2018-11-08
DC2        DC2-Generator-2                                    1              16128                    2              16192                    NULL           NULL                     2018-11-08
DC2        DC2-Generator-3                                    1              16128                    2              16192                    NULL           NULL                     2018-11-08
DC2        DC2-Generator-4                                    1              16128                    2              16192                    NULL           NULL                     2018-11-08
DC2        DC2-Generator-5                                    1              16128                    2              16192                    NULL           NULL                     2018-11-08
DC2        DC2-Generator-6                                    1              16128                    2              16192                    NULL           NULL                     2018-11-08
DC4        DC4-Generator-A                                    3              25881                    4              26007                    NULL           NULL                     2020-03-18
DC4        DC4-Generator-B                                    3              25881                    4              26007                    NULL           NULL                     2020-03-18
DC4        DC4-Generator-C                                    3              25881                    4              26007                    NULL           NULL                     2020-03-18
DC4        DC4-Generator-D                                    3              25881                    4              26007                    NULL           NULL                     2020-03-18
DC4        DC4-Generator-E                                    3              25881                    4              26007                    NULL           NULL                     2020-03-18
DC4        DC4-Generator-R                                    3              25881                    4              26007                    NULL           NULL                     2020-03-18
DC4        DC4-Generator-S                                    3              25881                    4              26007                    NULL           NULL                     2020-03-18
DC5        DC5-Generator-E                                    12             24079                    13             23774                    NULL           NULL                     2020-03-13
DC5        DC5-Generator-R                                    12             24079                    13             23774                    NULL           NULL                     2020-03-13
DC5        DC5-Generator-S                                    12             24079                    13             23774                    NULL           NULL                     2020-03-13
```

So I had to use DISTINCT so I could get it to one date.

Comment: The shape of your data makes this difficult. It would be much easier to work with if you essentially unpivoted the tank columns.

Comment: See above info that was added.

Comment: I'd recommend a different SQL query with IBX, Tank_ID, Level#, LevelValue, LastDate as columns instead.

Comment: Looking into that now.